How to create console application using cmd and open in VSCode?
How to create console application using cmd and open in VSCode?
I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I want to open my project in Vscode as well. I want to develop frontend in Vscode. How to create console application using cmd and open in VSCode?

Just open the folder  in VS Code (assuming you already installed C# support). Nothing more is needed. You don't need cmd, that's not a command line, that's the old DOS-style terminal.

Check the VS Code docs on C# here

Are you sure you don't want a class library to reference from your frontend code instead? Frontend to a console application sounds like an abnomination to me.

The command is the following:
dotnet new console -o MyConsoleApp
Then open it in code:
code MyConsoleApp
Once in VSCode: F1 and choose "Generate assets for build and debug"
